CORS fails in Blazor WASM even when the server (.NET Core) is allowing everything
We have a CORS problem in Blazor WASM with a server that I think should be allowing everything. We tested Firefox and Edge. The message error in the browser is not too detailed. It only tells us that CORS failed. There is no exception being thrown in the server. It works when the client is in the same machine as the server.
Here is our CORS configuration:
app.UseCors(options => {
     options
             .AllowCredentials()
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader()
             .SetIsOriginAllowed(hostName => true);
});

Probably the SetIsOriginAllowed line is not allowing all origins as we expected. Previously we had AllowAnyOrigin, but we had to change it after we added AllowCredentials. Is there a way to allow everything, including credentials?

Did you meet any error messages after configuring the SetIsOriginAllowed line? Have you tried changing the machine? From this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-the-allowed-origins, we can conclude that Specifying AllowAnyOrigin and AllowCredentials is an insecure configuration and can result in cross-site request forgery. The CORS service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured with both methods. This is insecure if the server is publicly accessible. You can try using WithOrigins() to specify multiple specific origins.
